# How to revert signed distance function back to binary image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, transform, distance, signed

So I used MATLAB's `bwdist` function to obtain the distance transform of a binary image. My question is, how do I transform a signed distance matrix back into a binary image?

```
D = bwdist(BW)
```

Specifically, is there a transform that can go back from `BW` -> `D`?

Answer (score 2):

If `D = bwdist(BW)`, how about `BW0 = D<=0`?

Consider the first example from the [`bwdist` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwdist.html#f1-287512):

```
bw = zeros(5,5); bw(2,2) = 1; bw(4,4) = 1
bw =
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0

[D,IDX] = bwdist(bw)

D =
    1.4142    1.0000    1.4142    2.2361    3.1623
    1.0000         0    1.0000    2.0000    2.2361
    1.4142    1.0000    1.4142    1.0000    1.4142
    2.2361    2.0000    1.0000         0    1.0000
    3.1623    2.2361    1.4142    1.0000    1.4142
```

To get back your binary image, you just want the points in the distance transform that are equal to zero (i.e. on a non-zero pixel in the original `bw`):

```
>> bw0 = D<=0
bw0 =
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0
>> isequal(bw,bw0)
ans =
     1
```

Comment: Since it is a signed distance transform, you want points in the distance transform that are **less than or equal** to zero. Zero pixels will give you only the edges of the connected components.